# integration of ngx-pinch-zoom with angular 4 error

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to integrate Pinch zoom with my angular 4 app, I am getting this error on the production, running fine in my local machine.

I am very new to angular, any help would be appreciated.

```
ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /home/circleci/www-arthcloud/node_modules/ngx-pinch-zoom/ngx-pinch-zoom.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/circleci/www-arthcloud/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Exited with code 1
```

Comment: The error says it expected version 3 of ngx-pinch but got version 4. Do you have any clue? Maybe you installed ngx-pinch version 3 and then updated package to version 4 and forgot about updating your code too?...

Comment: Have you tried `ng build --prod` locally?

Comment: @Reactgular , yes i have tried it and have got the same error

Comment: @Reactgular have you used some thing like this, then also please let me know,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngx-pinch-zoom version 1.0.0, its work fine with angular 4.

I don't know it is good practise or not but this also solved my problem, edit in the file ngx-pinch-zoom.metadeta.js version:4 to version:3